# Is the sum of non-identical zero truncated Poisson random variables also described as a zero truncated Poisson?

Tags: modeling, poisson-distribution

The sum of Poisson distributed random variables is itself Poisson distributed. Does this hold true for the sum of Zero Truncated Poisson distributed random variables?

Comment: What would the minimum possible value be of a sum of two or more random variables each of which has a minimum of $1$?

Comment: It's just a sum.  So the minimum possible value would be 1*the_number_of_random_variables, as each random variable is itself zero truncated

Comment: Yes, so then it cannot itself be truncated poisson?

Comment: @Kjetil comes to the point: what probability does a zero-truncated Poisson distribution assign to the value $1$?

Comment: I don't follow.  The sum can't have a value of zero.  The pfm of ZTP with x=1 would be \frac{\lambda}{(e^\lambda-1)}

Comment: A zero-truncated Poisson has a NON-zero probability of a getting a 1. A sum of two ZTP variables has a *zero* probability of getting a 1, so it *cannot* itself be simply ZTP.

Comment: Full solution is here:  https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/6304490.pdf  also relevant is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/963760/expectation-of-truncated-poisson-distribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Comment:** If you will look carefully at the comments of @whuber and @kjetil b halvorsen, you have a proof that the sum of 0-truncated Poisson random variables
is not a 0-truncated Poisson random variable. Maybe the following simple simulation of the sum of three of them will help you visualize why not.

```
set.seed(927)
x = rpois(10^5, 2);  xt = x[x>0];  nx=length(xt)
y = rpois(10^5, 3);  yt = y[y>0];  ny=length(yt)
z = rpois(10^5, 4);  zt = z[z>0];  nz=length(zt)
n = min(nx,ny,nz)
s = xt[1:n] + yt[1:n] + zt[1:n]  # just to keep vector lengths the same
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  3.000   8.000   9.000   9.557  11.000  24.000 
[1] 86516
```

$P(S < 3) = 0,$ so the distribution of $S$ cannot take values 0, 1, or 2.
Ten selected values of `s` are as follows:

```
cbind(xt[1:n], yt[1:n], zt[1:n], s)[900:909,]
             s
 [1,] 5 2 2  9
 [2,] 1 6 2  9
 [3,] 1 2 2  5
 [4,] 1 2 3  6
 [5,] 3 3 8 14
 [6,] 2 6 3 11
 [7,] 2 2 7 11
 [8,] 1 1 1  3  # smallest possible value
 [9,] 4 1 5 10
[10,] 3 1 4  8

hist(s, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

The (still fragmentary) relevant [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-truncated_Poisson_distribution) article has some information that may be
helpful.